# PrintWriter not writing to text file

Tags: java, save, printwriter

I'm trying to create a save feature which outputs stored data to a text file. I've tried using a Printwriter to write to the file and although I'm not getting any errors and the output seems to be correct, the text file remains blank. Here is my code:

```
public void saveConfiguration() throws IOException{
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("locos.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < currentTrains.size(); i++) {
        //confirm data is correct
        System.out.println(currentTrains.get(i).getAddress() + " " + 
                currentTrains.get(i).getName() + " " + "\n");

        //write to file
        pw.write(currentTrains.get(i).getAddress() + " " + 
                currentTrains.get(i).getName() + " " + "\n");
    }

    pw.close();

    //for testing
    System.out.println("File Saved");
}
```

Here's what's on the console:

```
8 class 08 

55 Jinty 

44 BR44 

File Saved
```

The above data that gets printed out is correct, but it's not getting written to the file. Can anyone explain how to do this properly?

Edit: I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm running this on a Tomcat server.

Comment: what is getting printed out on **locos.text** or is it a blank file?

Comment: Nothing is getting printed on locos.txt. The console output (except the last line) is what should be getting printed.

Comment: does this method create a blank locos.text file?

Comment: Not as far as I know. The file is actually already there although, it is  currently blank.

Comment: so delete the file and then run the program and see if it creates a new blank locos.txt file.

Comment: I just realised it created a new text file and wrote into it in the eclipse folder instead of the project folder. I have no idea why.

Comment: Thats because your working folder is the eclipse folder and not the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should try handling the **PrintWriter** and a **Filerwriter** instead...

## Example:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("locos.txt"));
```

Comment: That sort of helped, but the File end up in completely the wrong place  (the eclipse folder instead pf the project folder) for some reason.

Comment: yes, since you are not given a path, then the file will be created in the  classpath....